# VB.NET Iterating through objects of a structure

Tags: vb.net, iteration, structure

I have a structure "xyz" with 3 string objects in it. "foo" "bar" and "abc" I want to iterate through the structure and compare the names of the objects.

```
Structure xyz
    dim foo as string
    dim bar as string
    dim abc as string
End Structure
```

Pseudo:

```
For each x as object in xyz 
    if x.Name = "foo" then
        'bang
    end if
End each
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is possible but rarely (!!!) advisable. Rather, it’s usually a flaw in the design. Tell us why you need it so that we can give you optimal advice.

Comment: ...not as written, certainly.  Is your structure a collection of objects?  Will all the objects have a `Name` property?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I have a structure with about 50 strings whose names correspond to column captions in a datatable. I send a datarow to a function which needs to couple the values of the respective columns to the strings in the structure. Is there a better way of going about this?

Jeremy Holovacs no it's a collection of strings

Comment: Konrad is right.  You could get this information with reflection but it would hurt performance.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary then?

Comment: @ShawnSteward it's a 1-time thing... how bad could performance be affected? ---- You're right, a dictionary would fulfill the same function. But using reflection is the way one would go about doing this?

Comment: In that case it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: `it's a 1-time thing`  -- famous last words of a developer.

Comment: Alright guys, thanks a lot haha. I'll use a dictionary -.-

Comment: And remember you can use the `dict!foo` syntax if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is just a one time thing you're probably going to have an easier time using a Dictionary instead, but you could do this with Reflection if you prefer to keep the structure.

This little code snippet will list out each structure member for you in a `StringBuilder`.

```
Dim sbOutput As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim t As Type = GetType(xyz)
For Each p As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In t.GetFields()
  sbOutput.AppendLine(p.Name)
Next
```

Comment: can you "improve" your answer in adding reflection code to add VALUE of p.Name variable ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but I actually found myself needing this, too, and this was one of the top results Google came up for me, so I figured I'd contribute for anyone who comes by this way in the future.

In my case, I'm basically using the structure as a collection of strings that I can easily reference via `StrucName.Value1`, etc (basically an Enum of strings, [like asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312325/define-string-enum-in-vb-net)), and not have to worry as much about spell checking (as you'd have to do with a dictionary, whether you were using the `dict!foo` method as commented on above or not).  90% of my usage I just need one or two of the values at a time, but I have found a spot or two in my code where it'd be nicer/easier to loop through all of the member values and perform (essentially) the same set of actions with each of them vs listing each one out on its own line.

I found a good answer to this that doesn't use reflection [on another site](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/structure-members-how-to-iterate-through-them-123104/), where one of the commenters suggested either overriding the `ToString` function, or using a function that returns an array of the values.  Of course, technically, this still requires you writing out all the members of the structure again one more time, but if Reflection really is heavy on performance, then this may be better.

I ended up using the function to return an array method like below:

```
Public Structure StrucName
    Public Const Value1 As String = "Value1"
    Public Const Value2 As String = "Value2"
    Public Const Value3 As String = "Value3"
    'etc
    Public Shared Function GetMemberValues() As String()
        Return {Value1, Value2, Value3} 'etc
    End Function
End Structure
```

Then you can use it in code like this:

```
Dim values As String() = StrucName.GetMemberValues()
For Each value As String In values
    'do stuff
Next
```

If your structure is of multiple value types, then you can use an `ArrayList`, instead.

```
Public Structure StrucName
    Public Const Value1 As String = "Value1"
    Public Const Value2 As Integer = 2
    Public Const Value3 As Boolean = True
    'etc
    Public Shared Function GetMemberValues() As ArrayList
        Return New ArrayList From {Value1, Value2, Value3} 'etc
    End Function
End Structure
```

```
Dim values As ArrayList = StrucName.GetMemberValues()
For Each value As Object In values
    'do stuff
Next
```

And with the `ArrayList` method, if needed, you can get the type of the original value through `value.GetType()`, or any other similar operator or methods (so, with my example above, putting `MsgBox(value.GetType().ToString())` in our "do stuff" area will pop message boxes with "System.String", "System.Int32", and "System.Boolean").

And I imagine this could be adapted to a number of situations.  For example, if you needed both the member names and values, you could return a `Dictionary`:

```
Public Shared Function GetMemberValues() As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Return New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"Value1", Value1}, {"Value2", Value2}, {"Value3", Value3}} 'etc
End Function
```

Or, if you're using a new enough version of VB (VB 14 or later), you can use the `NameOf` operator ([MS Doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/nameof)):

```
Public Shared Function GetMemberValues() As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Return New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{NameOf(Value1), Value1}, {NameOf(Value2), Value2}, {NameOf(Value3), Value3}} 'etc
End Function
```

```
Dim values As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = StrucName.GetMemberValues()
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In values
    'do stuff
Next
```

And `kvp.value.GetType()` still holds up.